# Can Guard be configured to launch RubyMine's test runner?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, automated-tests, rubymine, guard, minitest

I've currently managed to get [Minitest](https://github.com/seattlerb/minitest) working with RubyMine's test runner, and I've **also** got Minitest working with [Guard](https://github.com/guard/guard).

Is there any way to combine the two so that Guard triggers the tests to run through RubyMine's test runner?

**Update:**

To clarify, I am aware to RubyMine's "Autotest" feature. However this lacks two significant benefits of Guard:

- Only the tests relevant for the change are run.
- The test environment is kept running, so no long load times.

However it lacks any sort of notification inside RubyMine when a test fails.

Can I get the best of both worlds to get the ultimate in convenience?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible yet, [vote for the open feature request](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RUBY-9903).

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use Guard in order to run tests automatically in RubyMine. RubyMine has a built-in feature for that. To activate it, press the "Toggle auto-test" button in the toolbar of the test results view.

Comment: This isn't quite what I'm looking for. I've updated the question to clarify.